# shared library not in ld cache

Tags: c++, g++, ld, jaus++

I'm attempting to use the JAUS++-2.110519 library. Following the included instructions, I have managed to install the library. I have verified the following:

**Shared libraries:**

```
libcxutils.so
libjauscore.so
libjausextras.so
libjausmobility.so
libtinyxml.so
```

are located in

```
/usr/local/lib/active
```

**Header files**

are located in

```
/usr/local/include/active
```

**Source code**

is located in

```
/usr/local/src/
```

Following the installation, it was mentioned in the instructions that the library path would need to be added to ld.so.conf. Since /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf already contained /usr/local/lib, running sudo ldconfig should have linked the newly installed library, however, I am not seeing said libraries in ld cache.

Running the following:

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libcxutils.so 
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libjauscore.so 
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libjausextras.so 
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libjausmobility.so 
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libtinyxml.so
```

returns nothing.

I have also created /etc/ld.so.conf.d/jaus.conf that contains the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/active
```

and ran sudo ldconfig afterwords. The results were the same, however.

Running nm -Ca on each of the *.so files appears to return valid input.

Why can't I get ldconfig to link this library properly? I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Because `/usr/local/lib/active` is not the same directory as `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: I have also tried adding my own .conf file to /etc/ld.so.conf/ that contained /usr/local/lib/active. This did not work either.

Comment: You need to add your own .conf file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory, assuming that `/etc/ld.so.conf` file contains the line `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` Then run `ldconfig` without parameters to update the cache (or reboot, don't remember exactly).

Comment: Please see above, I attempted creating my own jaus.conf within /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ but had the same results. /etc/ld.so.conf also contains /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf